# TSQL - creating from-to date table while ignoring in-between steps with conditions

Tags: sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a following table structure in the MS SQL server

[image: table 1]

Now, I want to get [in]  dates for each [id] according to these rules:

1. If there is [out] at 23:59 and [in] at 00:00 on the next day ignore these
2. If there is [out] and [in] on the same day ignore these

e.g. I should be getting following results:

| id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-07-30 | 2020-09-06 |
| 13 | 2020-07-31 | 2021-08-23 |
| 14 | 2020-07-31 | NULL |

...

| id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 2020-08-10 | 2020-09-21 |
| 23 | 2021-03-31 | 2021-04-24 |
| 24 | 2020-08-10 | NULL |

...

I do not care about the [out]s, so they are not mandatory. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I came with something like this:

```
select *from #temp1
EXCEPT
select t1.* from #temp1 t1
INNER join #temp1 t2
ON t1.id =t2.id
and (t1.[in] = DATEADD(minute,1,t2.[out]) or DAY(t1.[in]) = DAY(t2.[out]))
```

But I am losing some data, e.g. the second [in] for Id 23 from the example.

Comment: It is far preferable to provide your data in formatted text. You could even go so far as using a tool like [CSV to SQL Converter](https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) and dump the results into something like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95c01222a580bd419098590e7ad23cee) or [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3d2c5/1). Now we have your sample data in a form that we can use.

Comment: Please add the table structure and example data as a SQL script  so we can easily help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am confident there is a better solution than this. I wrestled with a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) approach, but I just could not get there.

My solution is to use the [LAG()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to figure out the previous values for particular columns and combine that with your date/time exclusion logic to define a group. And finally get the first and last values of each group.

```
SELECT
      a4.id
    , CONVERT (DATE, a4.First_in) AS [in]
    , CONVERT (DATE, a4.[out])    AS [out]
FROM  (
          SELECT
               a3.id
             , a3.[in]
             , a3.[out]
             , a3.id_group
             , FIRST_VALUE (a3.[in]) OVER (PARTITION BY a3.id_group ORDER BY a3.[in]) AS [First_in]
             , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY a3.id_group ORDER BY a3.[in] DESC)    AS [Row_number]
          FROM (
                   SELECT
                        a2.id
                      , a2.[in]
                      , a2.[out]
                      , a2.New_group
                      , SUM (a2.New_group) OVER (ORDER BY a2.id, a2.[in]) AS [id_group]
                   FROM (
                            SELECT
                                 a1.id
                               , a1.[in]
                               , a1.[out]
                               , IIF((id <> a1.Previous_id)
                                  OR (
                                         id = a1.Previous_id
                                     AND DATEADD (MINUTE, 1, a1.Previous_out) <> a1.[in] -- rule out 23:59 / 00:00 situations
                                     AND DATEDIFF (DAY, a1.Previous_out, a1.[in]) <> 0 -- rule out same day situations

                                     )
                                   , 1
                                   , 0) AS [New_group]
                            FROM (
                                     SELECT
                                          id
                                        , [in]
                                        , [out]
                                        , LAG (id) OVER (ORDER BY id)                      AS [Previous_id]
                                        , LAG ([out]) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [in]) AS [Previous_out]
                                     FROM MyTable
                                 ) a1
                        ) a2
               ) a3
      ) a4
WHERE a4.[Row_number] = 1;
```

[image]

Here is the [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e027e35ad4141b4604699c9ac6d18817).

Certainly my approach could be made more concise (i.e. less sub-queries), but I left them in there so they can be run from the inside out and you can see the progression of the logic. I think I could have avoided using the ROW_NUMBER() function if I could have gotten the [LAST_VALUE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function to work. Either I do not know how to use it or it is broken, likely the former.

Finally, I would recommend to not use keywords such as "in" for column names. I just makes things simpler.

Noel

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging a recursive CTE ([Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)) yields a cleaner approach imho. I'm not sure how it compares to Isaac's approach performance wise so you have to test that yourself.

Setup:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable;
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
   id  INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,[in]  VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL
  ,[out] VARCHAR(19)
);
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (12,'2020-07-30 00:00:00','2020-09-06 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (13,'2020-07-31 00:00:00','2020-11-02 13:00:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (13,'2020-11-02 13:30:00','2021-08-23 09:00:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (14,'2020-07-31 00:00:00','2021-11-04 11:00:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (14,'2021-11-04 11:05:00',NULL);
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (17,'2020-08-04 00:00:00','2021-11-03 11:00:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (17,'2021-11-03 11:05:00',NULL);
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (18,'2020-08-04 00:00:00','2021-10-22 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (19,'2020-08-05 00:00:00',NULL);
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (20,'2020-08-05 00:00:00','2021-04-10 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (21,'2020-08-05 14:00:00','2021-10-28 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (22,'2020-08-10 00:00:00',NULL);
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (23,'2020-08-10 00:00:00','2020-08-31 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (23,'2020-09-01 00:00:00','2020-09-14 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (23,'2020-09-15 00:00:00','2020-09-21 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (23,'2021-03-31 00:00:00','2021-04-01 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (23,'2021-04-02 00:00:00','2021-04-24 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (24,'2020-08-10 00:00:00','2020-08-16 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (24,'2020-08-17 00:00:00','2020-08-26 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (24,'2020-08-27 00:00:00','2020-09-12 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (24,'2020-09-13 00:00:00','2020-09-19 23:59:00');
INSERT INTO MyTable([id],[in],[out]) VALUES (24,'2020-09-20 00:00:00',NULL);
```

Solution:

```sql
WITH base AS 
(
    SELECT id, [in], out, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id, [in]) AS seq
    FROM (SELECT *, 
                 LAG(out) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [in]) AS prev_out 
          FROM MyTable) T
    WHERE prev_out IS NULL 
       OR (DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, [in]) != prev_out AND CAST([in] AS DATE) != CAST(prev_out AS DATE))
),

walker AS (
    SELECT id, [in], out, seq FROM base
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT walker.id, MyTable.[in], MyTable.out, walker.seq
    FROM MyTable
    INNER JOIN walker 
        ON MyTable.id = walker.id
        AND (DATEADD(MINUTE, 1, MyTable.[in]) = walker.out
        OR CAST(MyTable.[in] AS DATE) = CAST(walker.out AS DATE))
)

SELECT id,
       MIN(CAST([in] AS DATE)) AS [in],
       MAX(CAST(out AS DATE))  AS out
FROM walker
GROUP BY id, seq
ORDER BY id, seq, [in];
```

Output:

| id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 2020-07-30 | 2020-09-06 |
| 13 | 2020-07-31 | 2021-08-23 |
| 14 | 2020-07-31 | 2021-11-04 |
| 17 | 2020-08-04 | 2021-11-03 |
| 18 | 2020-08-04 | 2021-10-22 |
| 19 | 2020-08-05 | null |
| 20 | 2020-08-05 | 2021-04-10 |
| 21 | 2020-08-05 | 2021-10-28 |
| 22 | 2020-08-10 | null |
| 23 | 2020-08-10 | 2020-08-31 |
| 23 | 2021-03-31 | 2021-04-01 |
| 24 | 2020-08-10 | 2020-08-16 |

See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/60caca/1) for sample data (thanks to Isaac)

Explanation:

- In the first CTE (named 'base') we select the rows that form the start of a (potential) sequence. These rows don't have a proceeding row based on the rules specified in the OP. Each sequence gets a unique number assigned ([ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)).
- In the second CTE (named 'walker') we recursively walk the sequence from start to end, assigning the sequence number to each row and preserving the last 'out' value.
- Finally, we select the MIN(in) and MAX(out) grouped by sequence number to get the desired results.